# Adobe AIR - Updating native installer error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to get this [updating native installer](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/updating-air-apps-native-installer.html) tutorial to work with Flash (AIR 2.5) instead of Flex.
This error comes up:

> Call to a possibly undefined method updateApplication.

My code:

```
import com.riaspace.nativeUpdater.NativeUpdater;
updateApplication();
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the **NativeUpdater/src/Main.mxml**, you must create an instance of the NativeUpdater class, and then invoke the method on that instance.  In AS3:

```
import com.riaspace.nativeUpdater.NativeUpdater;

var updater:NativeUpdater = new NativeUpdater();
updater.updateApplication();
```